# How can I save user inputs in pandas without getting the data overwritten on the same row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Whenever I try to take new user inputs it overwrites the old one

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)


Comp_Name=input("Company Name/Symbol")

NI_before_Extraordinary_items=int(input("Net income before extraordinary items")) 

TA_beg_yr=int(input('Total assets at the beginning of the year'))

Cash_from_op=int(input("Cash flow from operations"))

Prev_NI_before_Extraordinary_items=int(input("Net income before extraordinary items of the last year"))

TA_t2=int(input('Beginning total assets of the previous year'))

for i in range(0,30):
    Company_stats={'index':[i], 'Company Name':[Comp_Name], 'Net Income': 
    [NI_before_Extraordinary_items],'Total Assets At Beg.of the year': 
    [TA_beg_yr],'Cash flow from operations':Cash_from_op}
    df=pd.DataFrame(Company_stats)
    df.set_index('index',inplace=True)
    i=i+1
    print(df)
```

I want to know if I can save my inputs in a row and then when the program runs again it saves the inputs on next row and so on

Comment: Please can you fix your code indentation.

Comment: indentation is pay of the python language syntax. Click `edit` to fix your code so that it is an running Minimum Viable Example.

Comment: So sorry it was probably messed up when I was copying it, thanks to @H.Bukhari it is now functional

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)
Comp_Name=input("Company Name/Symbol")
NI_before_Extraordinary_items=int(input("Net income before extraordinary items")) 
TA_beg_yr=int(input('Total assets at the beginning of the year'))
Cash_from_op=int(input("Cash flow from operations"))
Prev_NI_before_Extraordinary_items=int(input("Net income before extraordinary items of the last year"))
TA_t2=int(input('Beginning total assets of the previous year'))

for i in range(0,30):
    Company_stats={'index':[i], 'Company Name':[Comp_Name], 'Net Income': 
    [NI_before_Extraordinary_items],'Total Assets At Beg.of the year': 
    [TA_beg_yr],'Cash flow from operations':Cash_from_op}
    df=pd.DataFrame(Company_stats)
    #df.set_index('index',inplace=True)  <-- this is your problem...
    i=i+1
    #print(df)
```

input:

```
aaa, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555
```

output (in `.to_dict()` so that it's easier to read):

```
In [356]: df.to_dict()
Out[356]: 
{'Cash flow from operations': {0: 333},
 'Company Name': {0: 'aaa'},
 'Net Income': {0: 111},
 'Total Assets At Beg.of the year': {0: 222},
 'index': {0: 29}}
```

[`.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) method passes the `column label` or `list of column labels`.  Because it's in the `for` loop it gets reset with each iteration.  You'll need to move it outside the loop for it to be effective.